# Getting "Activex Component Cant Create Object"

Tags: c#, com, registry

I am trying to call C# function from VB Script code, I am getting "Activex Component cant create object" error.

I have done the following.

1. Created class library with ProgID, and Comvisible True and strong named
2. Registered the dll using RegAsm.exe /codebase dllpath ( Dll registered successfully, I am able to see that in Registry)
3. Creating object using VB Script code and calling C# function as below.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim testwfhandler
Set testwfhandler= CreateObject("CoreComponentWorkflow.WorkflowHandler")
If Not testwfhandler Is Nothing Then
    Call testwfhandler.test()
End If
Set testwfhandler= Nothing
```

Am executing this VB Script from third party application (Tridion workflow) installed in my server.

Don't know why am getting the above error,when i execute the same code from the server directly, it works fine.

test() this function will just create one log file and add some text inside that.

Comment: There are two versions of regasm.exe, a 32-bit and a 64-bit version.  Matters on a 64-bit operating system, pick the right one.  Or both.

Comment: I am using the regasm.exe in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 this location

Comment: The other one, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework directory, home of the 32-bit version of .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The answer is already provided through the comments but I figured it
>   makes sense to suppy a real answer so that others can easily find it
>   back.

Depending on how your VBScript is loaded/executed you should register your DLL using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of RegAsm.exe.

On a 64-bit OS, you should find the 32-bit version of regasm in, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe`

and 64-bit version of regasm should be in, 
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe`

If you want to run the VBScript yourself in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine see [How do I run a VBScript in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806584/how-do-i-run-a-vbscript-in-32-bit-mode-on-a-64-bit-machine)