# How do I concatenate a variable of the type Date/Time in my Insert statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This runs when the form loads:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TempVars("F_ID") = txtF_SNr.Value
    TempVars("Status") = txtStatus.Value
    TempVars("seit") = txtSeit.Value
    TempVars("bis") = txtBis.Value
    TempVars("von") = txtVon.Value
    TempVars("an") = txtAn.Value
    TempVars("Bemerkung") = txtBemerkung.Value
End Sub
```

txtSeit is the name of the text field in my form, bound to the column [seit] with the type of Date/Time in my table.

```
sql = "Insert into tblStatusFahrzeugeHistory (F_ID, Status, seit, bis, von, an, Bemerkung, Datenbank_Nutzer, Eintrag_erstellt_am, Eintrag_erstellt_um)" & _
"Select tblStatusFahrzeuge.F_ID, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Status, tblStatusFahrzeuge.seit, tblStatusFahrzeuge.bis, tblStatusFahrzeuge.von, tblStatusFahrzeuge.an, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Bemerkung, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Datenbank_Nutzer, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Eintrag_erstellt_am, tblStatusFahrzeuge.Eintrag_erstellt_um " & _
"From tblStatusFahrzeuge Where ( " & txtSeit.Value & " <> seit AND [F_ID] = '" & Me.txtF_SNr.Value & "') "
```

The sql statement above gives me the error:

> runtime error: '3075' syntax error in number in query expression...

How do I concatenate `txtSeit.Value` correctly? (Sorry im a beginner!)

Comment: I think you need an octothorpe (#) before and after the variable but inside the quotes. ```(#" & txtSeit.Value & "# <```

Comment: And the field should actually be at the left of the operator and the value at the right: Try `… Where ( [seit] <> #" & txtSeit.Value & "# AND …`

Comment: No, still the same error!

Comment: Consider using parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58571740/7296893. It's often easier, can handle locale changes, and makes sure you won't have SQL injection problems.

Comment: "seit" does not refer to the field in the table, it refers to the TempVars("seit") on the form load event. The concatenation above works perfect for integer values. And when i add the single quotation marks (one before and one after the double quotation marks) it works perfectly for string values as well.

Comment: F_ID is a text field? Octothorpe # is correct delimiter for date/time field. Why the TempVars if you don't use them? As constructed, the SQL references `seit` as table field, not the TempVars variable.

Comment: It seems like i need the TempVars beacause if i remove them the records wont be transferd into the new table correctly. My aim is: 
I have a continues form where the user can edit data, stored in the table, directly. Before the user can close the form or edit a different record he is asked if he wants to save his changes. I use the Before Update Event for that. If the user saves his changes the old record gets inserted to the History table. .. by the way, yes F_ID is a text field.

Comment: You are rigt June7i dont use the TempVars. The insert works completely without it. The actual problem is that the insert ONLY works when the text field, the user is entering data, is NOT empty. If it is empty and the user enters something it says you are about to append 0 rows. If i change it again after that, it works normaly because there is something in the field now!

Comment: What is purpose of this action? Why do you have History table? Is this an audit tracker? Is `seit` a text type field? As already noted by @Peh in second comment, you have field and parameter backwards. It can be made to work but suggest you swap.

Comment: Yes it tracks the status changes. Everytime someone changes the current status, the old status is transferd to a history table for reference. ...I will keep trying...