# connect MS Access to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to connect Ms Access database in CodeIgniter but I am getting following error
Message: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

My db connection.

```
$dbname = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/personal/naaz/TimeData 13april.mdb'; 
$access['dsn'] = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb)}; DBQ= {$dbname}";
$access['hostname'] = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb)}; DBQ= {$dbname}";
$access['username'] = "localhost";
$access['password'] = "";
$access['database'] = $dbname; 

$access['dbdriver'] = "odbc";
$access['dbprefix'] = "";
$access['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$access['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$access['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$access['cachedir'] = "";
$access['char_set'] = "utf8";
$access['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$access['swap_pre'] = '';
$access['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$access['stricton'] = FALSE;


$access_db = $this->load->database($access, true);

$result = $this->db->select('*')->get('user')->result_array(); 
print_r(json_encode($result));
```

please help anyone, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571741/231316)? Also, `(* .mdb)` looks suspicious, I'm pretty sure it should be `(*.mdb)`

Comment: I remove the space but it won't solve

Comment: Did you also go through the link that I provided? If so, please post screenshots of your ODBC drivers for the bit-ness that PHP is running as, 32 or 64.