# Read Access Database from NodeJs

Tags: node.js, odbc, ms-access-2010

### Problem

I need to access the data of an access database (*.mdb). The approach should be written in nodejs and be used by multiple users that should *NOT* be required to make any changes to the **ODBC** drivers list in Windows.

### Approaches

I've found the [`node-odbc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc). Looking at the documentation following snippet should work just fine:

```js
const db = require('odbc');

const cn = `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\some\\Dev\\db.mdb`;

db.connect(cn, (err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(connection);
});
```

Unfortunately is this the output I get:

```
[Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database] {
  odbcErrors: [
    {
      state: 'IM002',
      code: 0,
      message: '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The DSN could not be found and' +
        'there was no default driver specified'
    }
  ]
}
null
```

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to use Access from Node.JS, but magically without the use of any external drivers? Well, start [here](https://github.com/mdbtools/mdbtools/blob/dev/HACKING.md) I guess, and get to writing your own driver entirely in JavaScript. Good luck.

Comment: @ErikA thanks a lot but this isn't the point basically. I just don't want the user to download anything manually. Including the driver in some sort of binary would work fine aswell. But this thing aside, what driver would I need to download in order for this to work? Jet.OLEDB.12?

Comment: Well, the driver is proprietary and conflicts with existing installs in a different bitness, so you're out of luck if you want to install the driver automatically. You really either want your user to properly setup Access, or want to use a different database altogether.

Comment: See [Why am I getting “Data source name not found and no default driver specified” and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58571740/7296893) for the general case including a download link

Comment: Thanks a lot @ErikA, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I found another package called `node-adodb`. The following snippet works just fine for me with a password protected database.
Furthremore fixes this package the difference between x64 and x86 by using the SysWOW64 `cscripts.exe` file.

```js
const adodb = require('node-adodb');

const cn = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyPassword;';

const connection = adodb.open(cn);

connection.query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE firstname='John';").then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(err))
});
```