# Data source name not found and no default driver specified on web host

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to connect Access Database to my website via PHP,
Using PDO .
But, I'm getting this strange message

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I'm fully aware that there are multiple questions and answers regarding the same on Stack Over Flow but none of them worked for me.

this is my code to connect to my Access database .

```
<?php

$dbname = 'Sea_Service_Certificates.accdb';

if(!file_exists($dbname)){

    echo "not found";

}

$inp = $_POST["input"];

echo $inp . "<br>";   

try {

    $db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$dbname;Uid=; Pwd=;");
    
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "Select *from Certificate Details where PassportNumber = 
    "+$inp+";";

    $result = $db->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch();

    $name = $row["Name"];

    echo "<h1><a href='index.php'>$name</a></h1>";

} catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage()."<br>";

}

?>
```

The code works like a charm in local host but when I upload to my web host  which is BIGROCKS it doesn't work and throws the error.

I did every possible solution on the internet including customizing my php.ini file .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - please look at that and then make your code readable, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571740/why-am-i-getting-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-an)

Comment: Contact your hoster to install Access for you. They will likely say something like "No, no way, we're using Linux so we can't do it, and even if we were not, we wouldn't since Access is explicitly not supported for use in web services", and that'll be that. Then either consider buying a VPS with Windows and creating a terrible mess for yourself, or not using Access for web services.

Comment: Access is a terrible choice as a backend for a website, it's meant for desktop use with a single user or very small number of users. It will not scale well and support on Linux (which is probably what your hosting uses) isn't great, you're stuck with ODBC - which seems to be what's missing here. Use mysql, postgresql or even sqlite instead, they are all far better options

Comment: @ErikA thank you for the information , I have one more question that when I run   
                                      
                                   
````print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());````     on hoster side it shows me he has ODBC driver.  So they might already have Access

Comment: @BHNGROUP That lists the available PDO drivers, not the available ODBC drivers. See [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-data-source.php) for how to list the available ODBC drivers.

Comment: @ErikA Thank you so much for the information. will check some alternate options .