# Can't connect Navicat to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, odbc, navicat

I've installed NAVICAT app to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database.

When I try to connect, it says ODBC driver not found:

[image]

If I try to connect using HEIDI app, I have no issues.

Settings in Heidi:

[image]

Can you help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571740/why-am-i-getting-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified-an)

Comment: what is the  navicat version?
are you running x86 or x64?

Comment: @HenryEko I have the same issue, Navicat version is 15.0.14 x64. MS Sql server version Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64).

Answer (score 0):

You have no driver available. So, try to install the latest driver from [here].[1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

And then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Download driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339) and restart navicat